# Uber Driver app

Tags: uber-api, lyft-api

Most rideshare drivers drive for more than one comapany, they have two apps online and when a ride comes in and they accept it they have to go to the other app to go offline to keep from getting a ride from the other company. Would both Uber and Lyft's api allow an app that would automatically log the driver off the company that is not being used?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not currently possible with the apis and the integration does not exist to hook into the driver app to turning off driving mode in the app.

Comment: It's conceivable that a (centralized) app which manages trip requests for multiple services could do this automatically. This would require integration with the APIs of any services which the driver's signed into.

Comment: Technically it is not possible with the apis today for Uber/Lyft.